# How to get a flex column menu to stretch to 100% of the page without using 100vh on the main div

Tags: css, flexbox

I am working on an CMS, and I want to have a full 100% height.

How do I get my page a 100% height without the 100vh on the wrapper (which I am guessing this is the right way doing this).

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 font-family: arial;
}

.main-wrapper{
 display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;

 /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
}


.main-wrapper div{
}


.sidebar1{
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
 /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
 /*flex: 1;*/
 /*height: 100%;*/
 /*width: 10px;*/
 /*background-color: #29313c;*/
 background-color: #29313c;
 color: white;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 /*height: 100vh;*/
}

.sidebar1 .category{
 flex: 1;
 height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #90A4BB;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar1 .category:hover{
 color: white;
 background-color: #2E3C54;
}

.sidebar1 .category:not(:last-child){
 border-bottom: 1px solid #90A4BB;
}

.sidebar1 .category div{

}

.sidebar2{
    background-color: #dee3e7;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 330px;
    /*width: 330px;*/

/* flex: 1;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column; 
*/
}


.main-content{
 flex: 5;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column; 
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
 
 <div class="sidebar1">
  
  <a href="#" class="category">
   <div>AAA</div>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="category">
   <div>BBB</div>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="category">
   <div>Banana</div>
  </a>

 </div>

 <div class="sidebar2">
  
 </div>

 <div class="main-content">
  
 </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nyu1uma1/
(remove `hight: 100vh`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And `height: 100%;` to `.main-wrapper`

```
.main-wrapper{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyu1uma1/1/)**